# Discord Bot Reads Reaction to a Set Message

Tags: discord.js

I have my bot reading all messages in all channels and then assigning a role based on there only being the  emoji and nothing else.

**Const Above All Code**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const Yard = '694204522528243752';
```

**Code works to read messages**

```
bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.content == '') {
        message.member.roles.add(Yard);
    }
});
```

I am attempting to make the bot listen to a single message in a certain channel,  Then depending on the the reaction assigning a role/permission group to the user that placed the reactions.

**Trying to have bot read reactions instead**

```
bot.on('Reaction Assign Role', async (reaction, user) => {
    const filter = (reaction) => reaction.emoji.name === '';
    const rules = message.id('694538155336138752')

    await rules.message.id === filter;
        message.member.roles.add(Yard);
});
```

I am not sure how this is suppose to work.  I figure the bot is listening for reaction on a target message.  If message gets a reaction and the reaction is equal to the filter emoji then add role to the target user.

Not sure how to make the bot listen for reactions on a message by ID.  Once I get that I hope I can figure out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

This is more complicated than it sounds. You need to create a "raw" listener, which essentially tracks all changes in all channels. You can then focus on the reactions on a specific message.

This is how I did it:

```js
const events = {
    MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD: 'messageReactionAdd',
};

//you dont need to modify any of this:
bot.on('raw', async event => {
    if (!events.hasOwnProperty(event.t)) return;

    const { d: data } = event;
    const user = bot.users.get(data.user_id);
    const channel = bot.channels.get(data.channel_id) || await user.createDM();

    if (channel.messages.has(data.message_id)) return;

    const message = await channel.fetchMessage(data.message_id);
    const emojiKey = (data.emoji.id) ? `${data.emoji.name}:${data.emoji.id}` : data.emoji.name;
    const reaction = message.reactions.get(emojiKey);
    bot.emit(events[event.t], reaction, user);
})

//change the chnl variable so it gets the channel you want, the server ID for the correct server and the name of the emoji:
bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    let chnl= bot.channels.get(`289390221789757440`);
    if(reaction.emoji.name === 'NAMEHERE') {
        let msgserver = bot.guilds.get(`SERVERIDHERE`)
        let usr = await msgserver.fetchMember(user)
        console.log(reaction + ` ` + user)
    }
});
```

This should log the reaction and user any time someone reacts to it.

Comment: The top part of the code that you posted is a raw listener - the listener will listen for all message reaction at first.  Later with the second half of the code I will be filtering reactions of a certain message.

If I want to filter the reaction down to a specific emoji I would do that there as well?

Comment: Yes, at the part where I put "NAMEHERE"
You just put the name of the emoji in there

Comment: Attempted to use the above code, the line under |bot.on('raw', async event => {|  I am getting and error at the 5th character so I am assuming the if statement isn't good of because there are no messages

Comment: This is the error I am getting.  (node:30404) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: events is not defined

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot something. I edited my answer to include the definition of events.

Comment: I am now getting another error.  bot.users.get is not a function  I found a guide on line that showed me how to get it set up with partials.  I will keep messing with the code you gave me since I would rather have it link to a message and a reaction.

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using?

Comment: I have Discord.js v12

Answer (score 1):

This is using discord.js v12

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new discord.Client({
    partials: ['MESSAGE','REACTION']
});
const TOKEN = require('./config.json');
const Yard = '<roleID to Set>'
const MessageNumber = '<messageID to Watch>'

bot.login(TOKEN.token)

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(bot.user.tag + " has logged in.");
});

bot.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    console.log("Message Reaction Add Top");

    let applyRole = async () => {
        let emojiName = reaction.emoji.name;
        let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find;
        let member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id == user.id);
        if (role && member) {
            console.log("Role and Member Found");
            await member.roles.add(Yard);
        }
    }
    if (reaction.message.partial) {
        try {
            let msg = await reaction.message.fetch()
            console.log(msg.id);
            if (msg.id === MessageNumber) {
                console.log("Cached - Applied");
                applyRole();
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("Not a Partial");
        if (reaction.message.id === MessageNumber) {
            console.log("Not a Partial - applied")
            applyRole();
        }
    }
});
```